Postman/Selenium: Clicking a button/submitting a form
After logging into the site, I'm trying to bid on an item that is essentially equivalent to submitting a form (I think).
How does one go about this through API requests? Authentication is required as well.

I'm able to log in to the site by creating a session and making a post request.
Code sample I found on Github that I used for logging in:
def login(username, password):
    ip = "%d.%d.%d.%d" % (random.randint(1, 254),random.randint(1, 254),random.randint(1, 254),random.randint(1, 254))
    header = {
        "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/58.0.3029.110 Safari/537.36 SE 2.X MetaSr 1.0",
        "Accept-Language": "zh-CN,zh;q=0.9",
        "X-Forwarded-For": ip,
    }
    url = "https://buyee.jp/signup/login"

    session = requests.session()
    try:
        html = session.get(url, headers=header, timeout=20).text
    except Exception:
        return 1
    # print(html.request.headers)

    html = etree.HTML(html)
    token = html.xpath("//input[@name='login[_csrf_token]']/@value")[0]
    # print(token)

    data = {
        "login[mailAddress]": username,
        "login[password]": password,
        "login[_csrf_token]": token,
    }

    try:
        response = session.post(url, data=data, headers=header, timeout=20).text
    except Exception:
        return 1

    if ("我的主页" in response) or ("我的主頁" in response) or ("マイページ" in response) or ("My Page" in response):
        print("登陆成功: %s" % username)
        f = open("good.txt", "a+")
        f.write(username + "----" + password + "\n")
        f.close()
    else:
        print("登陆失败: %s----%s" % (username, password))

Should the same be done to place the bid?
I am thinking of avoiding Selenium because I'm trying to learn something new, and I don't like how brittle and slow it is.
The site does not have a public API, so is it necessary to reverse engineer the private API for what I'm trying to do?
